# Convert string to_datetime with wrong place day and month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ('08.02.2020', '21.02.2020', '2020.05.04')})
df
```

I do

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
0   2020-08-02
1   2020-02-21
2   2020-05-04
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But the first row must be

```
0   2020-02-08
```

If i do

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
0    02-08-2020
1    21-02-2020
2    04-05-2020
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Again 02-08-2020 instead of 08-02-2020

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], dayfirst=True)`?